# Android my app crash with the httpclient.execute(httpost)

Tags: php, android, post, http-post

I'm trying to send some string to some php file and get JSON variable back.
Now I'm stuck on the send my strings to my php file, I tried a lot of combinations from many tutorials, all of them crush in the:

```
httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

I really don't have any idea why.
P.S I gave the INTERNET permission in the manifest.xml file.
this is my code that's look working in any other people except me.

```
public void send()
{

    String  msg = "Some message text";


    if(msg.length()>0) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8888/file.php");

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "01"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", msg));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            httpclient.execute(httppost);// THE APP CRASH HERE!!!
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"All fields are required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

currently i just want to pass the send process (The JSON issue i'll handle next).

Thank you all.

This is the LogCat:

```
288-299/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.example.testphppost/.MainActivity

11-05 17:37:56.011      288-299/system_process W/WindowManager﹕ Failure taking screenshot for (328x546) to layer 21010

11-05 17:37:56.294        37-89/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property

11-05 17:37:56.542      288-302/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{40f0e4c8 u0 com.example.testphppost/.MainActivity}

11-05 17:37:56.762       37-184/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property

11-05 17:37:58.141    2147-2147/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 2147 SIG: 9

11-05 17:37:58.161      288-288/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Process com.example.testphppost (pid 2147) has died.

11-05 17:37:59.061      288-288/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40f27770 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@40d32668
```

Any idea?

Comment: You can not do Network operations on the UI Thread. Try to read the logcat.

Comment: add logcat outuput please :)

Comment: httpclient.execute cannot be ran on the ui thread. Toast.show must. one must go.

Comment: The Nerwork operation does was in the UI Thread but even after i moved it to own class same result...

Comment: And i deleted the Toast.show from the code, just to see if it crash again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are probably making the request on your main thread.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say something because you didn't provide any information about exception, but as said Sherif elKhatib, you need to send requests asynchronously. Try to look at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's look like you're trying perform network operation on your main thread, You Cant do THAT.
Try AsyncTask Or open new thread.

Answer (score 0):

Loopback address of android is 10.0.2.2 but your are using localhost(means 127.0.0.1) try to change it.And read this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Tried it, Same result. any other idea? pls

Comment: And I'm running MAMP on my MAC so I'm sure using "http://localhost:8888/file.php" should be ok, no?

Comment: Check the logcat whether it is Strict Mode error if it is try to copy the code `if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) { StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); }`